# iphone : in-app purchase bug on OS 4.0 processing one transaction two times 

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having a strange issue on OS 4.0. i am doing in-app purchase for a consumable product.

i start a transaction. my transaction is complete. i provide the content successfully. and transaction is removed from queue.

then i exit application. and wait for 1 or 2 minute. and run application again. when i run application again. and start my in-app observer. again some transaction is processed and my provide content method is being called. how this is possible ?

is any one else having the issue ? ... it is coming on OS 4.0

pls reply.

Answer (score 1):

Did you call [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction]; after you provided the content. Because if you didn't, StoreKit would think that there had been an error in the transaction and try to perform it again once you start the app again hence the transaction observer being called twice.